# Managed VM deploy failed because "env" setting is not supported

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-managed-vm

Trying to deploy a Java app to Google Appengine Managed VM. I'm using console `gcloud` and already prepared WAR file. Plus app.yaml.

Using following command:

```
gcloud preview app deploy ./build/libs/app.yaml
```

Right now it fails with:

```
Building and pushing image for module [default]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- DOCKER BUILD OUTPUT --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step 0 : FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/jetty9
---> 005014071b64
Step 1 : ADD webapp-webapp.war $JETTY_BASE/webapps/root.war
---> 3e9023930cc8
Removing intermediate container 342e8a2f5750
Successfully built 3e9023930cc8
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Beginning teardown of remote build environment (this may take a few seconds).
Updating module [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [400] "env" setting is not supported for this deployment.
```

I see similar error ([there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429506/gcloud-preview-app-deploy-error-response-400-env-setting-is-not-supported)) for `maven-gcloud-plugin` that happens when project is not configured as WAR. But notice that:

- i'm using plain command line tool `gcloud`, a latest version
- and my project is packaged into WAR already

Also i'm using following `app.yaml` (which i've got from maven plugin sources):

```
runtime: java
env: 2
api_version: 1
handlers:
  - url: .*
    script: dynamic
```

So the question, where from this error is coming from (docker image is already prepared at this moment, right?). What it means? And how to fix this?

**Update**
I noticed that it uses `FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/jetty9` for VM. But for Appengine it should be `FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/jetty9-compat`. I've tried to switch to *exploded app* instead of WAR, and it started using correct Docker base image. But still fails:

```
Building and pushing image for module [default]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- DOCKER BUILD OUTPUT --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step 0 : FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/jetty9-compat
---> 2ad8572ef3d8
Step 1 : ADD . /app/
---> b10f4bc6718e
Removing intermediate container 8b149f4baf9c
Successfully built b10f4bc6718e
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Beginning teardown of remote build environment (this may take a few seconds).
Updating module [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [400] "env" setting is not supported for this deployment.
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason was this line in `app.yaml`:

```
env: 2
```

it was too simple and too obvious to try to deploy w/o this option. Also, every doc, official and unofficial, mentions that you *need* to have `env: 2` option set to deploy your app as Appengine app. That's really strange.

Removing this line also changed base Docker image to `gcr.io/google_appengine/java-compat`. I guess it means that jetty images, including `jetty9-compat`, aren't compatible with Appengine apps